# Red5-server Target Build

Tags: eclipse, red5

I have recently downloaded the red5-server from Git-hub

https://github.com/Red5/red5-server

I have followed the instructions to build the jar files and Eclipse project successfully.

On the older version of Red5 I had no problem building the target server and installing applications by using the Eclipse plugin.

However, I can not find a resource to follow to figure out the next step to build a target server in red5-server directory. There are no zip or tar files created after build anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is on the readme, did you try the assemble profile?

[To package everything up (tarball/zip):](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server#build-from-source)

```
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean package -P assemble
```

Comment: That did not help. I have the tar and zip of the compiled target (red5-server-1.0.5-RELEASE) When I extract and  run as "Java Application" I get 
Bootstrap exception: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.red5.classloading.ClassLoaderBuilder.build(ClassLoaderBuilder.java:185)
 at org.red5.classloading.ClassLoaderBuilder.build(ClassLoaderBuilder.java:96)
 at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.bootStrap(Bootstrap.java:117)
 at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:48)
Bootstrap exit

Comment: Configuration: main class org.red5.server.Bootstrap working directory new target folder

Comment: does your extracted content have a lib directory with library jars in it? Also what do you mean by run as "Java Application"? If your expecting the jar to be executable, you're running it wrong. Use the sh or bat script to start it.

Comment: If I manually run the server from command line using sh it works but, on the previous releases (Ex 0.8,1.0) I was able to run the server from Eclipse using the run configurations. It looks like the run configurations does not see the right bootstrap.jar file. Thank you again.

Comment: Here is their older guide. https://docs.google.com/document/d/11ju06wbnEdC3ay0VuUxpKcXIoSx5NaHruNKuZQ4yOCk/edit page number 11 steps 7-8-9 does not work anymore.

Comment: If you look on the red5 users list, I believe there is a link for using the Red5 plugin that was created by the red5pro team; that may be your best bet.

Comment: Just to help out others having the similar issues. I just ignore the bootstrap error on Eclipse since it was working from the command line. I use the red5 Eclipse plugin (https://github.com/Red5/red5-eclipse-plugin) to get the "Dynamic web project" option on Eclipse. Creating the app is easy however right when it creates the Java code it complains about the red5.core classes. I will update if I figure it out.

Comment: I actually figured it out. I will post the solution here and the red5 git repo for others. I am now able to build a target red5 server, create plugin application and install it onto the new server created.